Class loading issue when running tests after flink upgrade to 1.19.1 from 1.15.2
When the flink version upgraded to 1.19.1 from 1.15.2. there is a test execution issue. We are using powermock to mock the classes in tests
java version 1.8
power mock 2.0.2
The Error is
org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Failed to execute job 'Flink Streaming Job'.
at flightRebooking.BoundLogicE2ETest.endToEndTest(E2ETest.java:93)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobInitializationException: Could not start the JobMaster.
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobInitializationException: Could not start the JobMaster.
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.flink.api.common.ExecutionConfig cannot be cast to org.apache.flink.api.common.ExecutionConfig
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.flink.api.common.ExecutionConfig cannot be cast to org.apache.flink.api.common.ExecutionConfig




Can you please include the test source code, your grade or pom and the whole stacktrace formatted so it can be read.

Added them in the question

Not as images. I can’t work with that. Copy and paste code and format with the ‘{}’ button. Also need enough of the code to simulate. This is very likely an mismatched versions issue.

It appears that Flink will have classloading issues if you introduce Powermock into your testing configuration.  Take a look at this posted issue Class loading issues when using Powermock.  Flink provides a good test harness and discusses what to do to mock out objects.  Please check out their unit test guide.
